# Valid annotation for parent is invalid for child

Tags: java, annotations, nullable

Hello I have parent class with argument with nullable annotation.

```
class Parent {

  @Nullable
  String name;

  Parent(@Nullable Strign name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Driver createDriver() {
    return new CommonDriver(name);
  }
}
```

I have multiple children classes, for most of them, the "name" argument can be null, but there are some for which it cannot.

```
class ChildC extends Parent {

  ChildC(@NotNull String name){
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  Driver createDriver() {
    return new ChildCDriver(name);
  }
}
```

and now I have issue (code inspection from intelliJ) inside ChildCDriver where name is @NotNull

Can this be solved somehow ?

Comment: What's the point of the child class? It shares a single field and otherwise overrides every other aspect of the behaviour. Just have parent and child be 2 implementations of a common interface. There is no need for inheritance here.

Comment: I first misread you question, thus the wrong, now deleted answer. Wondering: what does "I have issue" mean? If there is an error message, please include that in your question!

Comment: @Michael this is simplified example to the bone. Point is that in parent scope the parameter can be null but in the child scope it cannot.

Comment: @GhostCat Why do we use Nullable and NotNull annotations ? To let our IDE warn us about problems. At least I do. Now I got warning which is not valid. Also my code reviewer is always crazy about any warning.

Comment: @LukasHanacek Suppress it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reasonable code, but IntelliJ is not powerful enough to prove that the code is correct.  You need to suppress the warning.  Click on the line, press `Alt+Enter`, and find "Suppress" in that menu or a submenu.

The [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) can verify your code.  The complete code appears below.  The [`@FieldInvariant`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/framework/qual/FieldInvariant.html) annotation expresses that the field [has a more precise type in the subclass](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#field-invariants).

Without the `@FieldInvariant` annotation, the Nullness Checker issues this warning on line 27:

```
error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
    return new ChildCDriver(name);
                            ^
  found   : @Initialized @Nullable String
  required: @Initialized @NonNull String
```

With the `@FieldInvariant` annotation, the Nullness Checker proves the code is correct.

The below code example uses the Checker Framework's `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` annotations, but the Nullness Checker [also supports `@NotNull`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-related-work) so you can continue using JetBrains annotations in your code.

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.FieldInvariant;

class Parent {

  final @Nullable String name;

  Parent(@Nullable String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Driver createDriver() {
    return new CommonDriver(name);
  }
}

@FieldInvariant(qualifier = NonNull.class, field = "name")
class ChildC extends Parent {

  ChildC(@NonNull String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  Driver createDriver() {
    return new ChildCDriver(name);
  }
}

interface Driver {}

class CommonDriver implements Driver {
  CommonDriver(@Nullable String name) {}
}

class ChildCDriver implements Driver {
  ChildCDriver(@NonNull String name) {}
}
```